# How can I wrap a div around alert_urls?

Tags: layout

Currently, the alert links (when product is back in stock and price change alert) are simply wrapped in paragraph tags. I would like to surround both of these paragraph tags with `<div class="alert-links">[default alert urls code here]</div>`

I've looked round `/base/default` for some answers, and have found `base/default/template/productalert/product/view.phtml` but this only seems to plug the values from `` `/base/default/layout/productalert.xml `` - it looks like the phtml file is called twice, which outputs one paragraph tag after another. So I can't add my wrapper div in here.

I have also tried adding a div in `/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` around this piece of code:

`echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls');`

This works - the div then shows up in the source code - however, I'm using `alert.urls` as a reference elsewhere and appending another block under it. This causes the appended block to display *inside* the wrapper div, rather than under it.

So what's the best way to do this? Probably something involving `productalerts.xml`?

Comment: What if i want to add let's say an icon (`<i class="icon-alert"></i>`) beside text inside p tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice for you is to create wrapper block in productalerts.xml.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <reference name="alert.urls">
                <block type="core/template" name="alert.urls.wrapper" template="path/to/wrapper.phtml">
                     <block type="productalert/product_view" name="productalert.price" as="productalert_price" template="productalert/product/view.phtml">
                         <action method="preparePriceAlertData"/>
                         <action method="setHtmlClass"><value>alert-price link-price-alert</value></action>
                         <action method="setSignupLabel" translate="value"><value>Sign up for price alert</value></action>
                    </block>
                    <block type="productalert/product_view" name="productalert.stock" as="productalert_stock" template="productalert/product/view.phtml">
                        <action method="prepareStockAlertData"/>
                        <action method="setHtmlClass"><value>alert-stock link-stock-alert</value></action>
                        <action method="setSignupLabel" translate="value"><value>Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock</value></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Than in `/path/to/wrapper.phtml` you will do

```
<div class="alert-links">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('productalert_price');?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('productalert_stock');?>
</div>
```

Now your alert will be wrapped and you still can append other blocks under `alert.urls` and they will be displayed out of  `alert-links` div.

Comment: Perfect - exactly the solution I was looking for! Thanks.